Strict URL encode for HTTP link "preconnect" <...> in PHP
Premising that I just want to be nice and generate this in a safe way:
Link: <https://example.com>; rel="preconnect"

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Link
Premising that accordingly to the Mozilla Developers Documentation:

The URI (absolute or relative) must encode char codes greater than 255:

Question:
How would you "encode char codes greater than 255" in PHP?
I'm not looking for something that "works", I would like something that respects the standard (since in Internet "we" try to be permissive about what I accept, and rigid about what I give).
Thanks for any help for PHP.

Counter examples
The rawurlencode() (that follows RFC 3986) is incorrect because it escapes : and /:
echo rawurlencode('https://example.com/苗条');

Result (wrong):
https%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2F%E8%8B%97%E6%9D%A1


The urlencode() is also incorrect, same result (as expected):
echo urlencode('https://example.com/苗条');

Result (wrong):
https%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2F%E8%8B%97%E6%9D%A1

Workaround
I may just use rawurlencode() and then restore some characters. Stuff like:
echo str_replace(['%3A', '%2F', '%3C', '%3E'], [':', '/', '<', '>'], rawurlencode('https://example.com/苗条'));

Result (correct):
https://example.com/%E8%8B%97%E6%9D%A1

But, to respect the standard, I should probably loop chr() from zero to 255 to get all rawurlencode(chr(1..255)) to restore them... so this is becoming a bit hacky and overkill.
Current Approach
So, trying to be strict about "encode char codes greater than 255", so, I tried looping every single character(/byte?) and only run rawurlencode() if the result is 255, and it works well:
<?php
/**
 * Encode char codes greater than 255.
 * @param string $s
 * @return string
 */
function escape_link_header($s) {
    $result = '';
    foreach (mb_str_split($s) as $c) {
        if(mb_ord($c) > 255) {
            $c = rawurlencode($c);
        }
        $result .= $c;
    }
    return $result;
}

echo escape_link_header('https://example.com/苗条');

So the code is strict and the result seems correct to me:
https://example.com/%E8%8B%97%E6%9D%A1

Premising that this sounds a bit esoteric to me, is this a correct approach in PHP?
Any other approach to "encode char codes greater than 255" to have a safe <...> value for the Link HTTP header?
Again, the goal is to "just" strictly sanitize the <...> in this part:
header('Link: <https://example.com>; rel="preconnect"');

Thanks!

I'm surprised it's "greater than 255" and not "greater than 127"…!?

But generally: you cannot really encode a whole URL. You need to parse the URL into its parts (hostname, path etc), split the path into separate items, encode each one, and then put it back together. Or do this while putting together the URL in the first place, as a URL with non-ASCII characters in it isn't really a valid URL.

Thanks @deceze. Yep, that is also an additional source of confusing to me.

I suppose the 255 is simply a mistake. Further up on that same page, it says, "<uri-reference> - The URI reference, must be enclosed between < and > and URL encoded.", and that link is to the explanation of the "default" URL encoding in the WikiPedia.

Moreover Mozilla mentions this page: https://httpwg.org/specs/rfc8288.html#header but after 20 minutes of reading I'm still unsure about what should people do
